# Is there something omitted between started out and rather sceptical?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> Nicholas Sexton and Bradley Love, a pair of neuroscientists of
> University College London, started out ***rather sceptical*** about the
> supposed resemblance between natural and artificial neural networks.

Only adjectives can follow linking verb. But,start out or start does not have the part of speech of linking verb according to the mainstream dictionaries such as [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/start%20out), [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/start-out) and etc.

Is "as being" or something else omitted?

Comment: What might be confusing you here is that "started out" is a phrasal verb which has the meaning "began as".  So there is technically no omission here.

Comment: There's nothing missing. Those neuroscientists ***were initially sceptical*** (when they "started out" to investigate that supposed resemblance). Where have you found an authoritative source telling you ***to start out*** can't be adverbially modified by a word like ***sceptical***?

Comment: This sort of thing is fairly common, "They came into McDonald's hungry and left happy and full." I'm sure there are other questions about this, but not sure how to search for them!